# Youtube controls accessibility report

Tags: javascript, accessibility

I have the following iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ item.getFieldCollectionItem().field_youtube.value }}?playsinline=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&controls=2&modestbranding=1&autohide=1" frameborder="0" width="300" height="169"></iframe>
```

however the the buttons generated from the API don't have text inside making them inaccessible. The accessibility report I have it mentiones the following:

```
"Unlabelled 2 Button"
```

I assume referring to the "play" and "pause" buttons.

Is there a way to make these more accessible by having a descriptive text inside?

Comment: What does the DOM tree for those buttons look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fiddling with what YouTube gives us, I would recommend using a third-party video player that supports YouTube videos:

- [Able Player](http://ableplayer.github.io/ableplayer/) is available under the MIT licence. (Source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ableplayer/ableplayer).)
- [Plyr](https://plyr.io/) supports YouTube and Vimeo videos. The source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) is available under the MIT licence.
- [Video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) also supports YouTube videos if you add its [YouTube plug-in](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube).

There are other video players that devote attention to accessibility, but not all of them support YouTube videos.